# How to find the coefficients of raising and lowering operators operating on a state in $SU \left( 3 \right)$ representation?

Tags: particle-physics, operators, group-theory

In $SU \left( 2 \right)$ group, we calculated $C_{\pm} \left( \lambda , m \right)$ for $J_{\pm} \left| \lambda , m \right> = C_{\pm} \left( \lambda , m \right) \left| \lambda , m \right>$.

So I tried to find equivalently the $C_{T_{\pm}}$, $C_{U_{\pm}}$ and $C_{V_{\pm}}$ for $SU \left( 3 \right)$. We would need six equations to find these six coefficients. The first three I have are the commutations relations

$$
\begin{gathered}
\left< f , t_3 , y \left| \left[ T_+ , T_- \right] \right| f , t_3 , y \right> = \left< f , t_3 , y \left| 2 T_3 \right| f , t_3 , y \right> = 2 t_3 \\
\left< f , t_3 , y \left| \left[ U_+ , U_- \right] \right| f , t_3 , y \right> = \left< f , t_3 , y \left| \frac{3}{2} Y - T_3 \right| f , t_3 , y \right> = \frac{3}{2} y - t_3 \\
\left< f , t_3 , y \left| \left[ V_+ , V_- \right] \right| f , t_3 , y \right> = \left< f , t_3 , y \left| \frac{3}{2} Y + T_3 \right| f , t_3 , y \right> = \frac{3}{2} y + t_3 \\
\end{gathered}
$$

There are three more which comes from the anticommutators which you can compute with the anticommutation relation $\left\{ F^i , F^j \right\} = \frac{1}{3} \delta ^{i j} I_3 + d_{i j k} F^k$

$$
\left\{ T_+ , T_- \right\} = \frac{2}{3} I_3 + Y , \quad \left\{ U_+ , U_- \right\} = \frac{2}{3} I_3 - T_3 - \frac{1}{2} Y , \quad \left\{ V_+ , V_- \right\} = \frac{2}{3} I_3 + T_3 - \frac{1}{2} Y
$$

They would give you

$$
\begin{gathered}
\left< f , t_3 , y \left| \left\{ T_+ , T_- \right\} \right| f , t_3 , y \right> = \left< f , t_3 , y \left| \frac{2}{3} I_3 + Y \right| f , t_3 , y \right> = \frac{2}{3} + y \\
\left< f , t_3 , y \left| \left\{ U_+ , U_- \right\} \right| f , t_3 , y \right> = \left< f , t_3 , y \left| \frac{2}{3} I_3 - T_3 - \frac{1}{2} Y \right| f , t_3 , y \right> = \frac{2}{3} - t_3 - \frac{y}{2} \\
\left< f , t_3 , y \left| \left\{ V_+ , V_- \right\} \right| f , t_3 , y \right> = \left< f , t_3 , y \left| \frac{2}{3} I_3 + T_3 - \frac{1}{2} Y \right| f , t_3 , y \right> = \frac{2}{3} + t_3 - \frac{y}{2} \\
\end{gathered}
$$

In above equations, $Y = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} F_8$.

These equations are enough to determine factors $C_{T_{\pm}}$, $C_{U_{\pm}}$ and $C_{V_{\pm}}$ for $SU \left( 3 \right)$. However, in a representation $\left( p , q \right)$ of $SU \left( 3 \right)$, it is required that when you apply raising or lowering operators that will produce a state outside the hexagonal bounday, it had better give you zero.

For example, if state $\left| f , t_3 , y_{\max} \right>$ is the state with highest eigenvalue $y$, then $U_+ \left| f , t_3 , y_{\max} \right>$ should be zero. Unfortunately, this is not true for the factors we have.

Could anybody give me a hint on how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: for which irrep?  Have you looked at the Gelfand-Zeitlin matrix elements?  Those are pretty canonical.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Could you please make this more clear? Thanks!

Comment: You need first to specify the representation, i.e. the su3 equivalent to $j$.  For irreps of the type $(p,0)$ the matrix elements are easy.  For the general case see for instance Sec. VII of 
Alex, Arne, et al. "A numerical algorithm for the explicit calculation of SU (N) and SL (N, C) Clebsch–Gordan coefficients." Journal of Mathematical Physics 52.2 (2011): 023507.